# Multiprocessing & multithreading

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

In spite of learning python for 3 months I still can not understand: Where do we practically use multithreading and multiprocessing in python? It'd be better if I can get the asynchrony purpose too...
Also, do I critically need it to be hired on Junior Backend Python Developer (Django) profession?

Comment: apparently it's a nice thing to know for every kind of develop, not only junior

Comment: @NathanHughes Yeah, the typical CPython interpreter with GIL

Answer (score 0):

well i would say that multi threading has the same usage in most programming languages and it would be parallel processing as you might not want to queue all your processes on one thread at least if they dont need to be done in certain order for example in a video game rendering and physics and user input could be done in multiple threads as the physics dont need to wait for user input and they dont need to wait for the frame to render thus using multiple threads speeds things up now i haven't done that much back end programming but i would assume that you could use these things like a game server and a anti-cheat as the anti-cheat can just read user data like movement speed and the main logic loop in the server doesnt have to sacrifice time to process it because the anti-cheat thread can do it for and the asynchronous isnt really a benefit in all cases but it allows two threads to work in different speeds and for tasks that dont need to communicate like the rendering and the physics its a good deal that the physics can be looped separate from the rendering
hopefully this helped ik its messy but after someone better post something i can delete this